# how to set path for cloud foundary cf for ibm bluemix?

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I have installed cf-windows-386 in my windows8 pc. when i tried clicking cf.exe, is opening and closing all suddenly all the time. can any one help me ? is there any path to set for cf.exe  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to double click the actual executable to invoke "cf".  If CF has been set on your path correctly, as shown below:

[image: cf PATH example]

then you should be able to open a command prompt and type in "cf", as shown below:

[image: cf example]

For more information on how to start coding with the CF command line interface, see the article below:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/install_cli.html